# Costs of microcontroller with GSM module

Tags: microcontroller, gsm

First of all, I have to confess that I am a noob on this topic ;)

Currently I try to realize a pet project with a microcontroller, which is connected to a GSM module. I've done some research and found several GSM modules, which can be used with AT Commands - e.g. SIM900 or SIM908. But I only found suppliers selling these modules at 15 to 40 euros.

My objective is to develop a hardware, which easily could be scaled in production. But using a GSM module, which costs more than 15 euros, would blow away this idea. Now I have two questions:

1. Unfortunately I have no experience if these modules are so much cheaper if I buy them in higher quantities. How realistic is a price of 1-3 euros per piece and how many would I have to buy?
2. Which components do they use in mobile phones? You can get smartphone for as low as 40 euros. And a smartphone not only includes a GSM module, but also more expensive components (display, etc.). So how do the smartphone manufacturer handle this? Do they use a GSM module, too - or do they implement their own solution.

So you see, I am relatively new to this topic. Maybe someone could give me a hint how this industry works? ;)

Comment: Unless you have the know how to build your own, you're pretty well stuck with using GSM modules. Modules are for products that need GSM functionality integrated fast, building GSM fucntionality is for products that have people that know what they're doing working on them and need low BOM cost (cell phones).

Comment: Over 17,000 patents have been granted for 2G and 3G GSM technology. Therefore licensing fees can cost a lot.  I have used a GSM module that costs $29 in production quantities, and was told by the manufacturer $10 of that went to Qualcomm.  In order to keep costs down, the big players make deals so they don't have to pay per-unit royalties.  Samsung for example paid Qualcomm $1.3 billion for such an arrangement a few years ago.  This is how the "big boys" are able to get their prices so low.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for your comment. And are there any possibilities to get these gsm modules at a lower price? And at which quantity?

Comment: Thanks tcrosley! Bad news - but exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!
By the way: Are there any cheaper gsm modules that only use EDGE to save some fees?

Comment: [Here is a list](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/search-page/?Max!Download!Speed=236.8%20Kbps) of several EDGE modules.  The cheapest I've found are the [G24-EDGE](http://www.aliexpress.com/cheap/cheap-g24-edge.html) $25, and the [SL6087](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/SL6087-EDGE-module/410266_538631724.html) $30 + shipping.  I've used both of these and they work well.  Note: the G24 requires a special connector, and the SL6087 is a BGA.

Comment: Thanks again! Looks like the EDGE only modules are as expensive as the other ones ;)
This means I have to start thinking about my project again.

Comment: @Nelli In addition, as I mentioned in my previous comment, buying a bare module usually means either dealing with a proprietary connector or a SMD with a fine pitch or BGA, both of which are difficult to deal with manually (particularly the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to make a cell phone, perhaps not a smartphone, for a very low cost. For example, the Nokia 105 supposedly [costs only $14.20 to make](http://www.xbitlabs.com/news/mobile/display/20130702234531_Nokia_Manages_to_Make_Profit_on_20_Cell_Phone_Teardown.html).  But as the article says, this does *not* include any software costs, licensing or royalty fees (see my comment under the question for more information on that).  For a company like Nokia, this could be a fixed cost amortized over millions of devices.  The GSM/RF parts are listed as around $5.  But you'll never be able to buy these chips yourself for anything close to that.

[This article](http://www.digitimes.com/news/a20140225VL200.html) indicates the lowest BOM for a smartphone in China is currently $22.

Now when we're talking *real* smartphones, like the Samsung Galaxy S5 and the iPhone 5, things get a little crazy: the BOM for an S5 is [estimated to be around $250](http://press.ihs.com/press-release/design-supply-chain/samsung-galaxy-s5-carries-astronomical-bill-materials-ihs-teardown), and the iPhone 5 [around $200](https://technology.ihs.com/410378/iphone-5-carries-199-bom-virtual-teardown-reveals).  That is why they have to retail for $600 or so.

Comment: Very interesting - it explains everything! Thanks!